# How to initialize an index in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am modifying the code for one of my exercise. The modified code does run but I keep getting this error:

`"Undefined index: category_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex_starts\ch04_ex1\add_category.php on line 5"`

Could you please tell me how should I initialize an index for category_id in the following code?

Thanks!!

This is my code:

```
<?php  // Get the category data
  $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
  $name = $_POST['name']; // Validate inputs
  if ( empty($name) ) {
  $error = "Invalid category data. Check all fields and try again.";
  include('error.php');
  } else {
   // If valid, add the product to the database
   require_once('database.php');
   $query = "INSERT INTO categories
                (categoryID, categoryName)
             VALUES
                ('$category_id', '$name')";
   $db->exec($query);
   // Display the Category List page
   include('category_list.php'); 
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: could you also paste your $query in here?

Comment: In your database, put an index on category_id

Comment: @Maringo: no it's not related to a database index, it's because of the array does not contain that key

Answer (score 3):

Your POST data does not contain the category id.

```
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
```

this fails because `$_POST['category_id']` is not set. Check it by using `isset(`):

```
$category_id = isset($_POST['category_id']) ? $_POST['category_id'] : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using $ _POST or $ _GET to retrieve the variables from a form, you may encounter this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index 'fields of the table' in 'path of  php 
file being executes' on line 'current line'
```

To avoid this error, simply test whether the fields of the table were initialized with the function isset ().

```
// Before using $_POST['value']    
if (isset($_POST['value']))    
{    
          // Instructions if $_POST['value'] exist    
}
```

This type of error is notified depending on the configuration of the server.
It is not notified by default as it is considered as a minor error, corresponding to the constant E_NOTICE.

You can change the types of errors reported with the error_reporting function.

Answer (score 1):

You can write code like this

```
if(isset($_POST['category_id']) &&  isset($_POST['name']))
{
       // write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your $_POST array doesn't contain the index 'category_id'. The $_POST array is filled by form variables, send to the php file from a previous form submit. So depending on what you want to do, you could fill the `$category_id` variable with a default value if no post index is set:

```
$category_id = (isset($_POST['category_id']) ? $_POST['category_id'] : 1; 
// replace 1 with your default category
```

if you dont want to use the $_POST array you can choose to use the $_GET scope. This is filled with the url parameters. So if you call your site like index.php?category_id=1 you could simply assign this by

```
$category_id = (isset($_GET['category_id']) ? $_GET['category_id'] : 1; 
// replace 1 with your default category
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` it will not give you this warning like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['category_id']))
{
  $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
  //your code
}
?>
```